# Stdin, stdout, power function in python

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

Read four inputs a,b,c,d and print a^b+c^d
integers a,b,c,d are given on four separate lines

input
3
5
7
9

using stdout i want to print a^b+c^d in python
i tried

```
import sys
 y=[]
 for x in sys.stdin:
    y=sys.stdout.write(x)
    print(y[0]**y[1]+y[2]**y[3])]
```

but above code is not working

Comment: `sys.stdout.write()` doesn't return anything.  So calling `int()` on it is an error.

Comment: And even if it did work, that would make `y` a single integer, so it wouldn't be a list any more...

Comment: sys.stdout.write returning 3,5,7,9 but i need to print a^b+c^d

Comment: Your question would appear to be "How do I parse a string like `'a=3,b=5,c=7,d=9`' into a list like `[3,5,7,9]`?".

Comment: No, i want to print a^b+c^d

Comment: would you consider using `input()`?

Comment: If you parse your incoming string into a list, then performing that arithmetic would be very easy. `y=[int(x.split('=')[1]) for x in sys.stdin.split(',')]`, then you can print out your `print(y[0]**y[1]+y[2]**y[3])]`

Comment: It's unclear to me if the stdin stream contains '3,5,7,9' or 'a=3,b=5,c=7,d=9'

Comment: four separate lines 3 5 7 9

Comment: If you want your solution with the variable named `y` you could do `y = list(map(int, (input(), input(), input(), input())))` followed by `print(y[0]**y[1]+y[2]**y[3])`.

Comment: @matthias11 your code is working thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *input()* function to acquire data from the standard input stream.

Print the output.

```
a, b, c, d = [int(input()) for _ in range(4)]

print(a ** b + c ** d)
```

**Output:**

```
40353850
```

**Note:**

Implicit assumption is that the input is comprised of at least 4 lines (any additional lines will be ignored) and that each line represents a valid integer

Comment: Your code is working, thank you